# Automorpshism of a free abelian group of a free product

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $G=A_1*A_2*...*A_n*F_k$ be a free product, where each $A_i$ is free abelian of different rank (rank at least 2), and $F_k$ is a free group. Consider an arbitrary automorphism $\phi$ in $Aut(G)$, can we prove that $\phi(A_i)$ is conjugate to $A_i$ for all $i$? How?

Comment: This is an application of the Kurosh subgroup theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem

Comment: Can it be more specific? From Kurosh subgroup theorem, one can write $\phi(A_i)$ in the form of free products, but how to prove that this free product is exactly conjugate to $A_i$?

Comment: Since $\phi(A_i)$ is of rank at least 2, it doesn't split as a free product. Therefore it is conjugate into some $A_j$. Now apply the same observation to $\phi^{-1}$ to conclude.  Note that the conclusion is *not* that $\phi(A_i)$ is conjugate to $A_i$, but that there is a permutation $\sigma$ of the indices so that $\phi(A_i)$ is conjugate to $A_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: @HJRW The requirement that "each $A_i$ is free abelian of different rank" keeps $\phi(A_i)$ from being conjugate to $A_{\sigma(i)}$ unless $\sigma(i)=i$.

Comment: @LeeMosher -- so it does, I missed that hypothesis. Hmm... this looks increasingly like a homework problem.

Comment: So the condition can only deduce that $\phi(A_i)$ is conjugate to some $A_j$ (not necessarily $A_i$)? Can we deduce one step further to get the result that $\phi(A_i)$ is conjugate to $A_i$ itself, by the fact that each $A_i$ are of different rank and that $\phi$ is an automorphism of the group $G$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.